# How can I get a date range from a functional select/update/delete statement in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have the following functional statements:

```
a. ?[tab;enlist (within;`date;(enlist;(-;`.z.D;5);`.z.D));0b;()]

b. ?[tab;enlist (>;`date;(-;`.z.D;5));`.z.D));0b;()]

c. ?[tab;enlist (in;`date;2023.03.30 2023.03.31);`.z.D));0b;()]
```

What I want to do is this

`.util.getDateRange wc` (where wc can be one of the where clauses from the above functional statements) and I want the output to be

`2023.03.26 2023.03.31` for `a`

or

`2023.03.30 2023.03.31` for `c`

etc.

There are a lot of complexities (ie you have someone typing `select from tab where date>2023.03.15`).

I thought in order to avoid these complexities I could save the where clause to a variable `wc` let's say and do something like:

`` ?[([]date:.z.D + neg til .z.D-1950.01.01);wc;();`date] ``

... but I am ashamed to put such code in prod.

Comment: What's wrong with saving `wc` in a variable? That is often done. 
I find it a bit confusing to know exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: it's not the saving that i think it's wrong, it's the other part, generating a table with dates from 1950s to today and then apply the wc through a functional exec to get the min max date. basically ... i want to extract the date constraint from a functional select/delete/update statement

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution presented is simple and solves the problem. It does return a list of dates rather first/last in the range as in the example, but that could be fixed if required.

If your data is all partitioned by date, then it may be an improvement to use `.Q.PV` to get the list of partition values on disk, rather than creating some arbitrary date range.

```
?[([]date:.Q.PV);wc`a;();`date]
```